# Pandas: create json file from dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have dataframe

```
ID, visiting
111, 03.2015
111, 07.2015
111, 05.2016
222, 12.2013
222, 04.2016
333, 02.2014
333, 06.2015,
333, 11.2015
```

I need to get file like this(I need to specify all month since december 2013 to june 2016)

```
{
  "111": {
"2013-12": 0, 
"2014-01": 0, 
"2014-02": 0, 
"2014-03": 0, 
"2014-04": 0, 
"2014-05": 0, 
"2014-06": 0, 
"2014-07": 0, 
"2014-08": 0, 
"2014-09": 0, 
"2014-10": 0, 
"2014-11": 0, 
"2014-12": 0, 
"2015-01": 0, 
"2015-02": 0, 
"2015-03": 1, 
"2015-04": 0, 
"2015-05": 0, 
"2015-06": 0, 
"2015-07": 1, 
"2015-08": 0, 
"2015-09": 0, 
"2015-10": 0, 
"2015-11": 0, 
"2015-12": 0, 
"2016-01": 0, 
"2016-02": 0, 
"2016-03": 0, 
"2016-04": 0, 
"2016-05": 1, 
"2016-06": 0
}, 
  "222": { ...
}
}
```

How can I get that from Pandas?

Answer (score 0):

It would by more efficent using `groupby`s, but this gets the job done:

```
txt = """ID, visiting
111, 03.2015
111, 07.2015
111, 05.2016
222, 12.2013
222, 04.2016
333, 02.2014
333, 06.2015
333, 11.2015"""

split = [line.split(', ') for line in txt.split('\n')]

df = pd.DataFrame(split[1:], columns=split[0])

results = {}
for ID in df.ID.unique():
    results[ID] = {}

for year in range(2013, 2017):
    if year == 2013:
        months = [12]
    elif year == 2016:
        months = range(1, 7)
    else:
        months = range(1, 13)
    for month in months:
        search_text = '{:02d}.{}'.format(month, year)
        result_text = '{}-{:02d}'.format(year, month)
        for ID in df.ID.unique():
            if len(df[(df.ID == ID)&(df.visiting == search_text)]) > 0:
                boolean = 1
            else:
                boolean = 0
            results[ID][result_text] = boolean

import json
results = json.dumps(results)
```